# Python Groupby with sorting

Tags: python, python-3.x, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have Dataframe like:

```
         age    gender  occupation     zip_code
user_id             
1         24    M       technician      85711
2         53    F       other           94043
3         23    M       writer          32067
4         24    M       technician      43537
5         33    F       other           15213
6         42    M       executive       98101
7         57    M       administrator   91344
8         36    M       administrator   05201
9         29    M       student         01002
10        53    M       lawyer          90703
```

I have to get Male ratio per occupation and sort it from the most to the least.

I tried this and after this not able to proceed:

```
users.groupby(['occupation','gender']).gender.count()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide counts of `<occupation, gender>` by counts of `<gender>`:

```
i = df.groupby(['occupation' ,'gender']).gender.count() 
j = df.groupby('gender').gender.count()

(i / j).sort_values(ascending=False)

occupation     gender
other          F         1.000
technician     M         0.250
administrator  M         0.250
writer         M         0.125
student        M         0.125
lawyer         M         0.125
executive      M         0.125
Name: gender, dtype: float64
```

You can filter using `xs` to get ratios for just men:

```
(i / j).sort_values(ascending=False).xs('M', level=1)

occupation
technician       0.250
administrator    0.250
writer           0.125
student          0.125
lawyer           0.125
executive        0.125
Name: gender, dtype: float64
```

Comment: What i/j is doing, could you please explain

Comment: @subodhagrawal Division is aligned on the index. The first level of i's index, and j's index are aligned to correctly compute ratios.

Comment: but I am not getting the correct answer, I want to sort the ratio groupby gender= 'M'

Comment: @subodhagrawal Oh, oops. Check again.

Comment: @subodhagrawal You can only accept one answer. When you accepted the other, this was undone. Please take a look again.

Comment: @subodhagrawal The other thing is, you can accept only one, but you can upvote all answers. Good luck.

Comment: Yup....your answer looks easy to understand and 2nd one is lil'bit complex for me as I am a beginner in python.

Answer (score 2):

You can try  this:

```
df_out = df.groupby(['gender','occupation'])['gender'].count()

(df_out / df_out.sum(level=0)).loc['M'].sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
occupation
technician       0.250
administrator    0.250
writer           0.125
student          0.125
lawyer           0.125
executive        0.125
Name: gender, dtype: float64
```